# Need help with this proof.

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I'm not able to prove this:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}  {\cos {\frac{2k\pi}{n}}} = -1$$
Please help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the formula $\cos x=\operatorname{Re}(e^{ix})$?  If so, the result follows from the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Hint: if you included $k=0$, you'd be adding the $x$ coordinates of the vertices of a regular $n$-gon.

Comment: Do two cases n even and n odd. Note: $\cos \frac {2\pi}{n}*k = -\cos ({\pi - \frac {2\pi}{n}*k})$

Comment: .... or that you are add the x coordinates of the vertices of a regular n-gon.... as Robert Israel pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}2\sin\frac{\pi}{n}\cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}=\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\sin\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n}-\sin\frac{(2k-1)\pi }{n}\right)}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{n}-\sin\frac{\pi }{n}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}=\frac{-\sin\frac{\pi}{n}-\sin\frac{\pi }{n}}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}=-1$$

Comment: I tried exactly same approach at first, but found myself stuck in circular reasoning. You got it right. +1

Answer (score 2):

[image: Sadly I am away from my laptop right now so this is all I can do]

Sadly I am away from my laptop right now so this is all I can do.

Comment: There are some mistakes but I think those can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Set $\;\zeta=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}n}$. Remember that
$$1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\dots+\zeta^{n-1}=\frac{1-\zeta^n}{1-\zeta}.$$